# Undefined variable in class… but I define it

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a class for my database: class structure as below

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php"); // include(Username, passowrd, server and databaseName)
    class MySQLDatabase{
        private $connection;

        function __construct(){
            $this->openConnection();
        }

        public function openConnection(){
            $this->$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
            if(!$connection){
                die("Database connection failed: ".mysql_error);
            }
        }

    }
    $database = new MySQLDatabase();
    $db =&$database;

 ?>
```

then my first step was check this weather work or not. so I code index.php file as below

```
    <?php                   
require("../includes/database.php");                                       if(isset($database)){
echo "true";
}else{
echo "false";
}
    ?>
```

after that I run the program and I got errors as below. I can not understand the reason. I google it and there are no clear solution for this. is there are anyone can help me to understand why this happen and how to solve this?

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\wamp\www\waytoits\includes\database.php

```
on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  240792  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0008  249872  require( 'C:\wamp\www\waytoits\includes\database.php' ) ..\index.php:3
3   0.0013  250528  MySQLDatabase->__construct( )   ..\database.php:55
4   0.0013  250592  MySQLDatabase->openConnection( )    ..\database.php:15

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\waytoits\includes\database.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  240792  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0008  249872  require( 'C:\wamp\www\waytoits\includes\database.php' ) ..\index.php:3
3   0.0013  250528  MySQLDatabase->__construct( )   ..\database.php:55
4   0.0013  250592  MySQLDatabase->openConnection( )    ..\database.php:15
```

Comment: In context of that function, it should be `if (!$this->connection)` not `if (!$connection)`

Comment: `mysql_error` is going to issue notices about an undefined constant. You mean to use `mysqli_connect_error()` there for the last connection error issued by mysqli http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this::$connection` (with the `$` preserved) would refer to a static variable. Because you have a class variable you should access it via `$this->connection`

Also you need to use the same instructions in your `if`-statement.

Comment: don't understand why this is the accepted answer, as it has nothing to do with static variables. @EmCo answers seems more appropriate

Comment: you are right, I specified the wrong operator. For static variables it should be `$this::$connection` or better `self::$connection`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `$this->$connection` instead of `$this->connection` . Remove the `$` sign in `connection` and try again.